# Enable SSL on SOLR with existing cert

Tags: ssl, solr, ssl-certificate, keystore, keytool

I'm trying to enable SSL on SOLR with a SAN cert - I ran the keytool.exe to generate the .jks file from the cert file. That process went fine. I copied the .jks file over to the /etc directory, and then I enabled SSL in solr.in.cmd file. Then when I try to access the site, it tell me: "The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite." Is the issue with the cert, or issue with the way I generated the .jks file? Any help with this would be appreciated.

**MORE INFO:**

I learned that .cer files only contain the public key, and the private key is on the machine that generated the CSR. However, in this case, the machine that the cert is installed on is probably not the machine that the CSR was generated in. So, given this situation, how do I generate the keystore file to be used in SOLR?